# How to call an SQL Order Function from one table as reference to another?

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to sort the column 'Name' from my table named 'People' using the SQL Order DESC referencing the column 'ReportID' in a separate table named 'Report' with the following execution:

`cur.execute("""SELECT "Name" FROM People WHERE "ID" IN (SELECT "ID" FROM Report WHERE "ReportID" = ?) ORDER BY "Date" DESC""", (var,)`

Instead, I get the error prompt:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Date`

Any insights on what I can do to be able to call Date properly? Both tables are from the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `date` is only *visible* inside the subquery of the operator `IN`.

Join the tables and then you can use the column `date` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Name 
FROM People p INNER JOIN Report r 
ON r.ID = p.ID 
WHERE r.ReportID = ? 
ORDER BY r.Date DESC
```

You can remove `DISTINCT` if there is no case of duplicate matching rows in the table `Report`.